# In this income management My delete_record funciton not working

Tags: arrays, c, structure, file-handling

In this code I want to delete a specific record of user from file but I am not able to do so.
I use this approach to overwrite file. Firstly I made a temp file In which I write all other records except that  one I have to delete. Now I deleted original file and renamed Temp file as original file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct taxpayer
{
    char name[50];
    int Pancard_Number;
    int Mobileno;
    float income;
    float tax;
};

void add_record(FILE *file)
{
    struct taxpayer record;
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", record.name);
    printf("Enter 5-digit Pancard_number: ");
    scanf("%d", &record.Pancard_Number);
    printf("Enter Mobileno: ");
    scanf("%d", &record.Mobileno);
    printf("Enter income: ");
    scanf("%f", &record.income);

    if (record.income <= 25000)
    {
        record.tax = 0;
    }
    else if (record.income > 25000 && record.income <= 50000)
    {
        record.tax = (record.income - 25000) * 0.05;
    }
    else if (record.income > 50000 && record.income <= 75000)
    {
        record.tax = 1250 + ((record.income - 50000) * 0.2);
    }
    else if (record.income > 75000 && record.income <= 100000)
    {
        record.tax = 5520 + ((record.income - 75000) * 0.3);
    }
    else
    {
        record.tax = 11250 + ((record.income - 100000) * 0.4);
    }

    // record.tax = record.income * 0.1; // 10% tax rate
    fwrite(&record, sizeof(struct taxpayer), 1, file);
    printf("Record added successfully.\n");
}

void show_allrecord(FILE *file)
{
    // rewind(file);
    struct taxpayer record;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s  \n", "Name", "PancardNo.", "Income", "TaxPaid");
    while (fread(&record, sizeof(struct taxpayer), 1, file))
    {
        printf("%-20s %-19d Rs.%-19.2f Rs.%-17.2f  \n", record.name, record.Pancard_Number, record.income, record.tax);
    }
}

void search_record(FILE *file)
{
    // char name[50];
    int search;
    struct taxpayer record;
    printf("Enter pancard number to search: ");
    scanf("%d", &search);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while (fread(&record, sizeof(struct taxpayer), 1, file))
    {
        if (record.Pancard_Number == search)
        {
            printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s  \n", "Name", "PancardNo.", "Income", "TaxPaid");

            printf("%-20s %-19d Rs.%-19.2f Rs.%-17.2f  \n", record.name, record.Pancard_Number, record.income, record.tax);

            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Record not found.\n");
}

void edit_record(FILE *file)
{
    char name[50];
    struct taxpayer record;
    printf("Enter name to edit: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while (fread(&record, sizeof(struct taxpayer), 1, file))
    {
        if (strcmp(record.name, name) == 0)
        {
            printf("Enter new income: ");
            scanf("%f", &record.income);

            if (record.income <= 25000)
            {
                record.tax = 0;
            }
            else if (record.income > 25000 && record.income <= 50000)
            {
                record.tax = (record.income - 25000) * 0.05;
            }
            else if (record.income > 50000 && record.income <= 75000)
            {
                record.tax = 1250 + ((record.income - 50000) * 0.2);
            }
            else if (record.income > 75000 && record.income <= 100000)
            {
                record.tax = 5520 + ((record.income - 75000) * 0.3);
            }
            else
            {
                record.tax = 11250 + ((record.income - 100000) * 0.4);
            }

            // record.tax = record.income * 0.1;
            fseek(file, -sizeof(struct taxpayer), SEEK_CUR);
            fwrite(&record, sizeof(struct taxpayer), 1, file);
            printf("Record updated successfully.\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Record not found.\n");
}



void delete_record(FILE *file) {
    char name[30];
    printf("Enter the name of the taxpayer to delete: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    struct taxpayer record;
    int found = 0;

    // Create a temporary file
    FILE *temp = fopen("temp.txt", "wb");

    // Read each record from the file and write to the temporary file except for the one to be deleted
    while (fread(&record, sizeof(record), 1, file) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(record.name, name) == 0) {
            found = 1;
        }
         else {
            fwrite(&record, sizeof(record), 1, temp);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    fclose(temp);

    if (found) {
        // Delete the original file and rename the temporary file to the original file name
        remove("taxpayers.txt");
        rename("temp.txt", "taxpayers.txt");
        printf("Taxpayer with name %s has been deleted.\n", name);
    } else {
        printf("Taxpayer with name %s not found.\n", name);
        remove("temp.txt");
    }

    // Open the original file for appending
    file = fopen("taxpayers.txt", "ab");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("taxpayers.txt", "ab+");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int choice;
    do
    {
        printf("\n1. Add New Record\n");
        printf("2. List All Tax Payer along with Income Tax to be paid\n");
        printf("3. Search\n");
        printf("4. Edit\n");
        printf("5. Delete Record\n");
        printf("6. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            add_record(file);
            break;
        case 2:
            show_allrecord(file);
            break;
        case 3:
            search_record(file);
            break;
        case 4:
            edit_record(file);
            break;
        case 5:
            delete_record(file);
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("Exiting...\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 6);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to run all function correctly but  Once I run delete_record function I am not able to perform other functions also.

Please correct this code so that I am able to delete a specific record from file And also able to erform other function also

Comment: You say it doesn't work, but what do you see after you have tried your function? Do you see the temp file? Do you see the original file unchanged? What do you see printed? Etc, etc. The more information you can give about the error the easier it is to help.

Comment: One small error is that `file = fopen("taxpayers.txt", "ab");` should be `file = fopen("taxpayers.txt", "ab+");`

Comment: The variable `file` in the function `delete()` is local to the function. Even with the same name, it is NOT the same variable as used in `main()`. `delete()` should return the newly opened FILE pointer to the caller...

Comment: Or pass in a FILE **.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `delete_record()`: When you reopen the file in you do so with the incorrect mode "ab" but should be "ab+" as you intend to read from it.  This is a signal that you should avoid repeating yourself.
2. `delete_record()`: `file = fopen("taxpayers.txt", "ab+");` will update the copy of variable `file`, but it has no effect outside the function.  Either return the new `FILE *` or pass the argument in as `FILE **file`.  You can also, at least on Linux, eliminate the `fclose(file);` and change the subsequent `fopen() to:

```
    file = freopen("taxpayers.txt", "ab+", file)
```

This would be the smallest change to accomplish what you want.

3. (Left as exercise to reader) Always specify the maximum field width when reading a string with `scanf()`.
4. You don't validate your input.  For example if you have two people with the same name they will both be delete.  5 digit pan number doesn't check that you didn't put in 4 or 6 digits.
5. You should check that `scanf()` read the number of elements you expected.  If you give it invalid input to the menu, say, 'q', it will trigger an infinite loop.  The way to address gracefully is to flush the input buffer on error:

```
int flush() {
   for(;;) {
      int ch = getchar();
      if(ch == EOF || ch == '\n') return ch;
   }
}

// ...

        if(scanf("%d", &choice) != 1) {
              if(flush() == EOF) exit(0);
              continue;
        }
```

```
void delete_record(FILE *file) {
    char name[30];
    printf("Enter the name of the taxpayer to delete: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    struct taxpayer record;
    int found = 0;

    // Create a temporary file
    FILE *temp = fopen("temp.txt", "wb");

    // Read each record from the file and write to the temporary file except for the one to be deleted
    while (fread(&record, sizeof(record), 1, file) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(record.name, name) == 0) {
            found = 1;
        }
        else {
            fwrite(&record, sizeof(record), 1, temp);
        }
    }
    fclose(temp);

    if (found) {
        // Delete the original file and rename the temporary file to the original file name
        remove("taxpayers.txt");
        rename("temp.txt", "taxpayers.txt");
        printf("Taxpayer with name %s has been deleted.\n", name);
    } else {
        printf("Taxpayer with name %s not found.\n", name);
        remove("temp.txt");
    }

    // Open the original file for appending
    file = freopen("taxpayers.txt", "ab+", file);
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

and example session:

```
1. Add New Record
2. List All Tax Payer along with Income Tax to be paid
3. Search
4. Edit
5. Delete Record
6. Exit
Enter your choice: 2
Name                 PancardNo.           Income               TaxPaid               
jane                 23456               Rs.4.00                Rs.0.00               

1. Add New Record
2. List All Tax Payer along with Income Tax to be paid
3. Search
4. Edit
5. Delete Record
6. Exit
Enter your choice: 1
Enter name: bob
Enter 5-digit Pancard_number: 23456
Enter Mobileno: 2
Enter income: 2
Record added successfully.

1. Add New Record
2. List All Tax Payer along with Income Tax to be paid
3. Search
4. Edit
5. Delete Record
6. Exit
Enter your choice: 5
Enter the name of the taxpayer to delete: jane 
Taxpayer with name jane has been deleted.

1. Add New Record
2. List All Tax Payer along with Income Tax to be paid
3. Search
4. Edit
5. Delete Record
6. Exit
Enter your choice: 2
Name                 PancardNo.           Income               TaxPaid               
bob                  23456               Rs.2.00                Rs.0.00
```

Comment: Thanks Senior for help, I will Keep in mind these things.

Comment: Also when I am editing existing  record  ,It is writing new record not updating old one.

Comment: Sorry senior ,This is my first question on this platform. Sir caan you tell me why You use *delete_record instead of delete record.

Comment: Yes, I know, which is why I am helping you along :-)  Look up [mre].